# Vertically align a stretched flexbox item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I wonder how I can set an item inside a `display: flex` container to `align-self: stretch` and let it be vertically aligned in the middle at the same time.

I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fw5pttme/) to showcase my problem. The element "My Logo Text"
should be at the same vertical level as "My Banner" and "Right Container"

Comment: You logo text will be a single line?

Comment: Yes. But i don't want to set a fixed-height, padding-top, margin-top or line-height on it. There must be a nicer solution, I hope.

Comment: See @wscourge answer then

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%
}
```

Comment: why to change the html?

Comment: You are right, it is not necessary. Thanks, I'm changing my answer :).

Comment: don't forget 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

If `My Logo Text` is a **single line** you could use `line-height:50px;` to fix the problem.

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/fw5pttme/1/).

If you want to know more about `line-height` read this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/

```css
.flex-container{
  color: #fff;
  background: #3c3c3c;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.logo{
  background: #f06;
  align-self: stretch;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height:50px;
}
.title{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item logo">My Logo Text</div>
  <div class="flex-item title">My Banner</div>
  <div class="flex-item "><span>Right Container</span></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want a "fixed height" you can use:

```
.logo {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center
}
```

As said @wscourge in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I exchanged `align-self: stretch` with `height:100%;` and added `display:flex` to the `.logo` itself. This centers the content of the .logo itself while maintaining height of 100%.

https://jsfiddle.net/fw5pttme/3/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with an extra div and calling flex a second time. There might be a cleaner solution. I'll play around with it a bit more and let you know.

```css
.flex-container {
  color: #fff;
  background: #3c3c3c;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex-item {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.logo-container {
  display:flex;
  background: #f06;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.logo {
  align-self: center;
}
.title {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item logo-container">
    <div class="logo">My Logo Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item title">My Banner</div>
  <div class="flex-item "><span>Right Container</span>
  </div>
</div>
```